# Inferring types with a key of a type object in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i have a type and I would like to dynamically update its fields based on a key value I pass into a function. However, the way I would like to do it (brokenFunction) is giving me an error on the assignment: Type '34' is not assignable to type 'never' and Type '34' is not assignable to type 'never'. workingFunction works but is not as handy. Does anyone have a way to make this work? I'm guessing it involves generics but I still dont understand why the type guards arent working.....

```
interface Todo {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}

const todo = {
  id: 1,
  text: "Buy milk",
};


function brokenFunction(x: Todo, field: keyof Todo): void {
  if (typeof field === 'number') {
    x[field] = 34
  } else if (typeof field === 'string') {
    x[field] = 'something else'
  }
}


function workingFunction(x: Todo, field: keyof Todo): void {
  if (field == 'id') {
    x[field] = 2345
  } else if (field == 'text') {
    x[field] = 'asdfsf'
  }
}
```

playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUD2ATTqDewqqI2AXKmAK4C2ARrANxGrQAeEFAzhDOAObMAvsGBJMYHqxx4AvARakKARgA0Ldp1QAiAEJUAnqhogANgGtt6oc1FwqYJBBATUdGJnNQwAMQdOXMAAKNgosXFVUOBAoU3JULwNMOAwZAEoKADdMUgViEBSgiAMAByhkqJi41Fla1AByanpYerS84lQ2AG1o2OwAXRrUAGYAFhYhVFiuNALUItLylN7q2vl6nj4wflb24m6VgaGNzBooCAALASnTGfqJ4BE7f2dXAHdMGHMBP0dX4NCqQilT6FESFXCmAyqGyuUI%20UKhxq61Iu3hHQOVSO8gATGMAKwTG4zEiIrHIhqaNEsfY9LGDdYILjYOBcOD3YgiERAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `brokenFunction()`, the type of the `field` parameter is `"id" | "text"`, meaning it is either the string `"id"` or the string `"text"`.  In both cases, at runtime, `typeof field` will be `"string"`.  And thus the first `if` block will never be reached, and the second one will always be reached:

```
  if (typeof field === 'number') {
    x[field] = 34; // can never happen
  } else if (typeof field === 'string') {
    x[field] = 'something else'; // might be an error
  }
```

I guess you probably meant something like this instead, which also doesn't work:

```
function brokenFunction2(x: Todo, field: keyof Todo): void {
  if (typeof x[field] === 'number') {
    x[field] = 34; // error!
  } else if (typeof x[field] === 'string') {
    x[field] = 'something else'; // error!
  }
}
```

That's because the compiler just doesn't perform the kind of control-flow analysis you are trying to get here; you want the compiler to narrow the type of `field` based on `typeof x[field]`, but it doesn't.  This is related to a [known issue, microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) in which such bracket access for properties does not trigger control flow analysis narrowing.  Oh well.

So, how can we address it?  One possible way is to make a [user-defined type guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function that explicitly tells the compiler what you're looking for:

```
function fieldGuard<T, V>(
  x: T,
  k: keyof T,
  guard: (x: any) => x is V
): k is { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T] {
  return guard(x[k]);
}
```

The function `fieldGuard()` takes an object `x`, a key of that object `k`, and a guard function you'd like to check the property `x[k]` against.  It then narrows the type of the key `k` depending on the result of the guard.  Then this works:

```
function okayFunction(x: Todo, field: keyof Todo): void {
  if (fieldGuard(x, field, (y): y is number => typeof y === 'number')) {
    x[field] = 34;
  } else if (fieldGuard(x, field, (y): y is string => typeof y === 'string')) {
    x[field] = "something else";
  }
}
```

It's somewhat tedious, but it comes fairly close to your original logic and the compiler is willing to do at least some of the checking for you.  Without a fix to microsoft/TypeScript#10530, I can't come up with anything much better than the above or just checking the keys themselves as in your `workingFunction()`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUD2ATTqDewqqI2AXKmAK4C2ARrANxGrQAeEFAzhDOAObMAvsGBJMYHqxx4AvARakKARgA0Ldp1QAiAEJUAnqhogANgGtt6oc1FwqYJBBATUdGJnNQwAMQdOXMAAKNgosXFVUOBAoU3JULwNMOAwZAEoKADdMUgViEBSgiAMAByhkqJi41Fla1AByanpYerS84lQ2AG1o2OwAXRrUAGYAFkZUAHpJ1CQEMEooTNhUAAsEErKwFiFUWK40AtQi0vKU3ura+XqePjB+VvbibouBoZvMGigIVYE90wO9Qm02MIH4qwgbjQ8z2MA8MB2wBEdn8zlc7k83j8jjRYAATCEwjJIq8KIkKuFMBlUNlcoR8oVimUKi8qm8rg0mgwYI96R1WX1BvIxsCZrB4QBCHb-A4kRmnFk9NlCuo3XgCXksZ5KwXvLifb6-e4yqBAqZiuGYGBS4giZH2HGBSp9ADiVAQMGwAB50JEAGoAPiCLFCGHUxHMZKgSRSvpY-HdnoohNQ8wMbVkAc6JC4qD9wGp5hzBFQXQA0iQFuTY-0ALQAfjC5cGUA43mwub9qHrqArFDASxWQi61Ywgz5MG+VBgCwTHuwIRH-TSwhRjtcngQBmxAQkKcpJLZUZjqVw1Np2HaRyCrzd85Ch76kSC6YoRhAua5K0zrAVKSMHKNLQ3KtG0fLaq8QojOM0r7IchS3omC5sI+cTPq+qDvrmtx-D+TJnJhNSqjh9ygU8nQ6nEUHaPqXw-H8cHaMwtpImuu4LAA7la5gCDuuL7sSzpxMeFLpFkOSXny16vERDSkJqHQUZBQx4mMACssEAvBxwyaqmgKfylHsg0CBcNgcBcHA9SIiIqBAA)